# Binding Vue checkbox group to nested object using v-for

Tags: vue.js

I have a nested data set in Vue that I would like to bind to several checkbox groups. The code is as follows ([jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0k9u4oLa/21/)):

```
<div id="app">
  <b-form-checkbox-group 
    v-model="checked"
    v-for="(opts, key) in optGroups"
    :key="key"
    v-model="checked[key]"
  >
    <button @click="checkAll(key)">Check All</button>
    <b-form-checkbox 
      v-for="opt in opts"
      :key="opt.value"
      :value="opt.value"
    >{{ opt.text }}</b-form-checkbox>
  </b-form-checkbox-group>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    optGroups: {
        g1: [
        { value: 'val1', text: 'value 1' },
        { value: 'val2', text: 'value 2' },
        { value: 'val3', text: 'value 3' }
      ],
      g2: [
        { value: 'val4', text: 'value 4' },
        { value: 'val5', text: 'value 5' },
        { value: 'val6', text: 'value 6' }
      ]
    },
    checked: {
        g1: ['val1'],
      g2: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkAll(groupKey) {
        this.checked[groupKey] = this.optGroups[groupKey].map(
        opt => opt.value
      );
    }
  }
})
```

I would like the checkboxes to respect the values set in the `checked` object. on startup. I would like easch `Check All` button to check all boxes in its group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove second `v-model` directive in `b-form-checkbox-group` - this `v-model="checked"`.

Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0k9u4oLa/26/

Comment: Guess it's going to be one of those weeks... Cheers!